# linux heartbeat losing packets

Tags: linux, troubleshooting, heartbeat

I am using linux heartbeat to keep ldirectord running on my webservers.

My logs show **heartbeat WARN: 1 lost packet(s)** every couple of minutes, and I'm having trouble figuring out why.

I have tried altering DEADTIME and WARNTIME in /etc/ha.d/ha.cf, but these appear to address **late packets**, not **lost packets**.

**netstat -ai** reports no errors on my interfaces

Any idea what is causing these warnings, and how I can address them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try looking at congestion on the switch, icmp has less priority then ip, heartbeat is icmp.

use a dedicated switch for inter server communication.

Stuart

Comment: Great suggestion.  These are virtual machines, so I'm not SURE that this will make a difference, but I will try setting up a dedicated virtual switch/vlan for heartbeat.  Thanks.